# How To Target a Specific Select List and Return It's Value Used Over Mulitple Rows

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML code where in this case, I have three rows of records where one of the table cells in these three records is a select/option list. I have individually assigned unique ids for these three select lists via the ids of "selectLOV1", "selectLOV2" and "selectLOV3"

```
<table summary="Contacts" class="uReport uReportStandard">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="CONTCT_NM">Contact Name</th>
            <th id="TEL_NO">Telephone
                <br/>No.</th>
            <th id="STATE">State</th>
            <th id="REAS">Reason</th>
            <th id="DATE_CALLED">Date
                <br/>Contacted</th>
            <th id="MPA_COMMENT">Comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td headers="CONTCT_NM">Contact A</td>
            <td headers="TEL_NO">123456</td>
            <td headers="STATE">VIC</td>
            <td headers="REAS">
                <input type="hidden" name="f01" value="16919" />
                <input type="hidden" name="f02" value="100319" />
                <select name="f10" id="selectLOV1" class="lov_select">
                    <option value="0">--- Please select a reason ---</option>
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Contacted / Spoken</option>
                    <option value="2">Contacted / Unavailable</option>
                    <option value="3">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td headers="DATE_CALLED">
                <input type="text" name="f20" size="14" maxlength="2000" value="30/08/2012 09:42"
                class="date_val" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#B0C4DE;border:1px solid #999999;"
                />
            </td>
            <td headers="COMMENT">
                <textarea name="f30" rows="2" cols="30" wrap="VIRTUAL">Contact A</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers="CONTCT_NM">Contact B</td>
            <td headers="TEL_NO">123456</td>
            <td headers="STATE">VIC</td>
            <td headers="REAS">
                <input type="hidden" name="f01" value="16919" />
                <input type="hidden" name="f02" value="100314" />
                <select name="f10" id="selectLOV2" class="lov_select">
                    <option value="0">--- Please select a reason ---</option>
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Contacted / Spoken</option>
                    <option value="2">Contacted / Unavailable</option>
                    <option value="3">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td headers="DATE_CALLED">
                <input type="text" name="f20" size="14" maxlength="2000" value="30/08/2012 09:42"
                class="date_val" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#B0C4DE;border:1px solid #999999;"
                />
            </td>
            <td headers="COMMENT">
                <textarea name="f30" rows="2" cols="30" wrap="VIRTUAL">Contact B</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers="CONTCT_NM">Contact C</td>
            <td headers="TEL_NO">123456</td>
            <td headers="STATE">VIC</td>
            <td headers="REAS">
                <input type="hidden" name="f01" value="16919" />
                <input type="hidden" name="f02" value="100312" />
                <select name="f10" id="selectLOV3" class="lov_select">
                    <option value="0">--- Please select a reason ---</option>
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Contacted / Spoken</option>
                    <option value="2">Contacted / Unavailable</option>
                    <option value="3">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td headers="DATE_CALLED">
                <input type="text" name="f20" size="14" maxlength="2000" value="30/08/2012 09:42"
                class="date_val" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#B0C4DE;border:1px solid #999999;"
                />
            </td>
            <td headers="COMMENT">
                <textarea name="f30" rows="2" cols="30" wrap="VIRTUAL">Contact C</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Based on this, I am unsure via the use of jQuery how to target the select list I am currently on as I need a means of returning the option value for the specific row that I am on, when changed.

I am basically trying to return the select list option for the row that I am on using jQuery and I'm unsure how to achieve this as I need to perform some processing based on selection list value which can be 0, 1, 2 or 3 in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by - `I need a means of returning the option value for the specific row that I am on, when changed.`

Comment: Pls see my comment under Rahul's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can do it simply like this

```
$('.lov_select').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KPkZR/)

Comment: Thanks Rahul - exactly what I was after. Sorry to others if I didn't explain properly. FYI, what I tried was $(".lov_select option").val() which obviously wasn't correct.